# Is there a way to trigger chat bot on Facebook post reply?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There is a Webhook in Facebook for triggering outside service when the user send a message to page. ([reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/product-overview/conversation#receive_messages)) Is there a way to actively send message to user (e.g. on page visit / reply to a post on page)?

I have done some search on Google but nothing's found. I know it is a big topic, so full answer is not needed. I would just like to know if it is possible and some keywords for Google search or some reference to documentation would be enough.

Comment: Of course not. Why should anyone get pestered with unsolicited messages they did not ask for, just because they visited a page?

Comment: @CBroe How about if the user reply to a post? Like asking for details of a event and so we can immediately reply to the user's inquiry?

Comment: If they comment on a post, your page can respond with a private comment reply. (But that has nothing to do with messenger.)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at,
 1. LUIS , https://www.luis.ai/ApplicationList
 2. BotFrameWork , https://dev.botframework.com/
 3. GitRepo botbuilder , https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder
 4. ChatFuel , https://chatfuel.com/

Comment: Looking into other, but chatfuel only do a reply message after the user sent a message first.

Comment: check botbuilder repo, where conversationUpdate method available which pings user when they visit to our page.

Comment: Are you able to crack it?

Comment: At this moment, no.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta , Thanks buddy, If you find above post help full then up vote it.. :)

Comment: @chetanmekha I have played with Luis and Bot framework earlier. Do you wanna play git git with me :)

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta sure dude! but currently i am using other repository for hosting chatbots. :)

Comment: @chetanmekha Do you have anything to share?